# azure databricks vscode: ERROR: TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined

Tags: azure, visual-studio-code, databricks

Originally, the connection between vscode and Databricks worked absolutely fine. [Databricks-connect](https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/databricks-connect.html) and the extension [Databricks vscode](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=paiqo.databricks-vscode) worked seamlessly together and I had no problem until last week. Last week the workspaces of Databricks vscode did not properly load as seen here: [empty databricks workspaces](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MCiex.png).

I checked the paiqo.databricks-vscode and this is the error that I got:
`ERROR: TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined`

I also did some digging and I only found one discussed which could point me in the right direction:
https://githubmemory.com/repo/paiqo/Databricks-VSCode/issues/48

It has something to do with the SSH connection but I do not know which settings I need to adjust in vscode or azure. If someone could point me in the right direction that would be great.

Comment: This looks like a bug in the extension code. 

It's probably best to create an issue in their GitHub repository https://github.com/paiqo/Databricks-VSCode/issues